# When trying to convert an HTML file to a PDF file my program seems to hang at pdf.save(ms)

Tags: html, pdf, filestream, memorystream, pdfsharp

I have two programs, one that writes an html file based on data in SQL DB (this works fine) After the file is saved, the following program should pick it up and convert it to PDF for the 1st program to mail it to the clients. The problem is with the conversion, I have been struggling like this for weeks, tried iTextSharp, wkhtmltopdf, Migradoc and Pdfsharp etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code for the converter:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program prg = new Program();

    Console.Write("Please enter File Name"+"\n");
    string Filename = Console.ReadLine();
    string FilePath = @"C:\Users\BB\Documents\Reports\" + Filename;
    var fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                              FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete);
    string content;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    PdfSharpConvert(content, FilePath);
}

public static void PdfSharpConvert(string html,string Filepath)
{

    Byte[] res = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {

        var pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
        pdf.Save(ms); ---> this is where the code hangs
        res = ms.ToArray();
        FileStream file = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\BB\\Documents\\Reports\\Report_1499.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        File.WriteAllBytes(Filepath,res);

    }
}
```

And here is the HTML file's contents:

```
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Untitled Page</title><style type="text/css">
      PRE   {page-break-before: always;}

      @media print
      {
      .footer
      {
      position: absolute; bottom: 0px;
      }
      }

      </style></head><body style="margin:0"><div style="width: 100%; position:absolute; top: 0; z-index:-1"><img src="logo1.png" height="257" border="0" alt="" /></div><div style="margin-bottom: 100px;"><br /></div><table style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px;" width="750" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0"><tr><td width="400" align="left"><font color="#3b6f85"><b>HELPMEKAAR-STUDIEFONDS</b></font><br /><font color="#000000">
              Address: PO Box 1223<br />Parrow   7499<br /><br /><br /></font><font color="#000000">
              Postal Code: <br /></font></td></tr></table><table style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px; margin-top:15px" width="780" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"><tr><td align="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px; border-bottom:1px medium; border-top:0px; border-left:0px; border-right:0px" width="780">
            Acccount Number: </td></tr><tr><td align="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px; border-bottom:1px medium; border-top:0px; border-left:0px; border-right:0px" width="780">
            Date: </td></tr><tr><td align="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px; border-bottom:1px medium; border-top:0px; border-left:0px; border-right:0px" width="780">
            Statement Period:  - <br /></td></tr></table><br /><table style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px;" width="780" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"><tr><td width="200" valign="top"><b>Agreement Details</b></td></tr><tr><td width="200" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            Asset Description:<br />
            In the name of:<br />
            Financed Amount:<br />
            Finance Contract Start Date:<br />
            Finance Contract Expiry Date:<br />
            Contract Term:<br />
            Interest Rate:<br />
            Balance Outstanding:<br />
            Installment Amount:<br />
            Installment Frequency:<br />
            Outstanding Capital Balance:<br />
            Amount in Advance:<br />
            Amount in Arrears:<br /></td><td width="380" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff"><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></td></tr></table><br /><br /><table style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px;" width="780" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"><tr><td width="400" valign="top"><b>Summary of Transactions for Statement Period</b></td></tr></table><table style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px;" width="780" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"><tr><td width="200" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            Payments Received:<br />
            Interest:<br />
            Fees Levied:<br />
            Insurance Cost Levied:<br />
            Collection Cost:<br />
            Admin Cost:<br />
            Legal Fees Incurred:<br />
            Other Debits / Credits:<br /></td><td width="380" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff"><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></td></tr></table><br /><table style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px;" width="780" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"><tr><td width="200" valign="top"><b>Installment Details</b></td></tr><tr><td width="200" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            Installment Due Date:<br />
            Installment Due Amount:<br /><b>Minus</b> Advance:<br /><b>Plus Arrears:</b><br /><b>Amount Due:</b><br /></td><td width="380" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff"><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></td></tr></table><br /><div class="footer"><table style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:10px;" width="780" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0"><tr><td style="text-align:center"><b>Helpmekaar-Studiefonds</b><br />
            Barry van der Merwe bestuur, met die hulp van drie administratiewe beamptes, mevv. Nita van Zyl, Retha Geldenhuys en Wilma Steenkamp.
            Helpmekaar-Studiefonds McIntyrestraat 72 Parow Posbus 1223 Parow 7499.
            Tel.: 021 930 8155 / 021 930 3195 Faks: 021 930 7436, www.helpmekaarfonds.org
            An authorised Financial Services and Credit Provider.
          </td></tr></table></div><br /><PRE /><table style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px; margin-top:15px" width="780" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"><tr><td align="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px; border-bottom:1px medium; border-top:0px; border-left:0px; border-right:0px" width="850">
            Acccount Number: </td></tr><tr><td align="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px; border-bottom:1px medium; border-top:0px; border-left:0px; border-right:0px" width="850">
            Date: </td></tr><tr><td align="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px; border-bottom:1px medium; border-top:0px; border-left:0px; border-right:0px" width="850">
            Statement Period:  - <br /></td></tr></table><br /><br /><table style="border:1px medium; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px;" rules="all" frame="border" width="780" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" bordercolor="#000000"><tr><th style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px solid; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" align="left" width="130">Date</th><th style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px solid; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" align="left" width="450">Transaction</th><th style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px solid; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" align="left" width="120">Debit</th><th style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px solid; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" align="left" width="120">Credit</th><th style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px solid; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px solid; border-color:#000;" align="left" width="120">Balance</th></tr><tr><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="95"><b>2016-12-01</b></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="490"><b>Opening Balance</b></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="90" align="right" /><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="90" align="right" /><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px solid; border-color:#000;" width="90" align="right"><b /></td></tr><tr><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="95">2016-12-31</td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="490">Total Debits</td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="90" align="right" /><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="90" align="right" /><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px solid; border-color:#000;" width="90" align="right" /></tr><tr><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="95">2016-12-31</td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="490">Total Credits</td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="90" align="right" /><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="90" align="right" /><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px solid; border-color:#000;" width="90" align="right" /></tr><tr><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="95"><b>2016-12-31</b></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="490"><b>Balance carried forward</b></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="90" align="right" /><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px medium; border-color:#000;" width="90" align="right" /><td style="border-bottom:1px solid; border-top:1px medium; border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px solid; border-color:#000;" width="90" align="right"><b /></td></tr></table><br /><br /><table style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:10px;" width="780" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0"><tr><td style="text-align:center"><b>Helpmekaar-Studiefonds</b><br />
            Barry van der Merwe bestuur, met die hulp van drie administratiewe beamptes, mevv. Nita van Zyl, Retha Geldenhuys en Wilma Steenkamp.
            Helpmekaar-Studiefonds McIntyrestraat 72 Parow Posbus 1223 Parow 7499.
            Tel.: 021 930 8155 / 021 930 3195 Faks: 021 930 7436, www.helpmekaarfonds.org
            An authorised Financial Services and Credit Provider.
          </td></tr></table><br /></body></html>
```

Comment: Why don't you call `pdf.Save(Filepath);` to save to the file directly? I don't see why it should hang while writing to the stream, so writing to the file may not work either. We need your `html` to replicate the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply, I have added the html. have also tried pdf.Save(filepath) nothing happens as well.

Comment: Which PDFsharp version are you using? If it is v1.50.4589-beta4 then please try 1.50.4000-beta3b instead.